# Disable choosing date in the future in QCalendarWidget

Tags: c++, qt

This is the standard calendar

[image: calendar]

I want to make **the dates from tomorrow in this calendar appear in grey**, and **we can not select the date from tomorrow on**, we can only select date from the past until today. Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QcgDatabase * db, int hostid, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(calendar_clicked(QTableWidgetItem*)));
}

void MyClass::calendar_clicked(QTableWidgetItem* tableitem) 
{
    int column = tableitem->column();
    clicked_item = tableitem;

    if (!calendar) {
        calendar = new QCalendarWidget();
    }
    calendar->setWindowTitle("Calendar");
    calendar->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    calendar->show();
    connect(calendar, SIGNAL(activated(const QDate&)), this, SLOT(date_selected(const QDate&)));
}

void MyClass::date_selected(const QDate&)
{
    if (!clicked_item) {
        return;
    }
    QIcon icon(":/myclass/icon/calendar.png");
    clicked_item->setIcon(icon);
    clicked_item->setText(calendar->selectedDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    calendar->close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
calendar->setMaximumDate(QDate::currentDate());
```

Comment: Just one more small question: normally we have to click double to choose the date in calendar. How can we click only once to choose the date ?

Comment: I never tried it but it _could_ be possible by deriving from this class or installing an event filter maybe... I'll need to check and cannot give answer right now. Try and if you won't find ask this question

Comment: thank you! I will try to create a new class for that. I hoped that we can do it with only one command like above.

Comment: It _might_ be possible, I need to check. I am curious by myself ))))

Comment: Try this: attach your slot to `QCalendarWidget::clicked(const QDate & date)` signal, then in that slot do `calendar->setSelectedDate(date) ` plus maybe do what you now do on selectionChanged event (call that business function)